# Wallet Integration with 0x

Tags: 0x

We are building a decentralized wallet. There are some questions about the integration with 0x.

1. Is there any direct way to add fee
2. If there is any API parameters to add fee.

Please share your contact email where we can contact with you.

Comment: It might just be me failing to understand the question.  But is there a wallet named 0x??

Comment: We wants to integrate our wallet with 0x which will act as aggregator here to provide Swap services

Answer (score 0):

Fees can be added to an order using the takerFee and makerFee fields of the Order struct. These fields are specified in units of the order's "fee asset"

Answer (score 0):

When using 0x API you can set buyTokenPercentageFee and feeRecipient parameters to receive fees on each swap made by your users. You can check here all documentation related to 0x API quote api: https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote